# TCPDF writeHTML()

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am working on two column layout input comes from an editor which has images and text. Images can come as one column or full width. Everything works fine when I insert images in one column. But when I insert image as 2 column it fits perfectly in the column but the text after that is somewhat not aligned.

Text covers the after space correctly but when it goes to second column some space from the top till where the image ends on the first column is blank and starts after that.

```
if ($this->myResetColumn) {
    $this->resetColumns();
    $this->setEqualColumns($this->myCols, $this->myWidth);
    $this->setXY($this->GetX(), $this->GetY());
    $this->selectColumn();
}

$this->writeHTML($content, true, false, true, false, $align);
```

**Second Question**

It there a way, I can make few checks while the `writeHTML()` function is executing or I have to change the function itself, which will not be a good idea to change the source code.
For AddPage, I override it, after the line at the end like this

```
$this->startPage($orientation, $format, $tocpage);

if (condition) {
    // some function call
}
```

but `writeHTML()` is a lengthy function to override and it will lose many options it has.